# Prisma2 cannot convert to or from a Postgres value of type `timestamptz`

Tags: prisma

I created all my Postgres tables using knex timestampz and now I get this error when trying to query anything. One possible solution is to convert all the columns to timestamp without timezone, but could I keep timezone and solve this error with photon?